# current date minus one month crystal report

Tags: date, crystal-reports

How to calculate current date(month) minus one month in crystal report?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To subtract one month from the current date use

`DateAdd ("m", -1, CurrentDate)`

If you just want the month number use this

`Month(DateAdd ("m", -1, CurrentDate))`

If you are trying to get the month name use this

`MonthName(Month(DateAdd ("m", -1, CurrentDate)))`